# Partitioning a graph into k similar subgraphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, cluster-analysis

I have a graph which is connected and the edges have weights on them. Less the weight between an edge, the more closer the adjoining vertices are. I want to divide the graph into k smaller subgraphs such that nodes in all the subgraphs are very similar.

In other words, I need to cluster the graph. Can somebody suggest clustering algorithms that are suitable for graphs and have less time comlexity(lesser than O(n^2))?

Comment: Why do you mean exactly by "similar nodes"?

Answer (score 0):

Clustering is difficult problem that in general could be solved *exaclty* by brute force only. So in case of efficient algorithms your have to rely on some heuristic approach. In case if you can solve your problem as a vertex clustering task, you can try something like [k-means](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means), but it could be slow on larger data sets.

For graph specifically, I would suggest using [MCL](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~xyan/classes/CS595D-2009winter/MCL_Presentation2.pdf) algorithm on your problem. MCL seems to be efficient in a lot of cases. It uses randomized flow simulation to detect clusters in weighted/unweighted graphs. Basic idea is that flow gathers within a cluster, while links between clusters tend to be less *saturated*.